# Show always deactivated scrollbar in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I load grid into Kendo splitter. But when I move splitter bar, a horizontal grid height increases as a horizontal scroll bar appears. This causes the splitter to have height as there was no horizontal scroll bar in the grid, the pane containing grid also has the height before the scroll bar appeared. This produces the pane to have a vertical scroll bar, which I don't want to have. 'OnResize' event of the splitter does not deal with this appearing scroll bar properly.

Comment: Please, would you mind posting some code (preferably in JSBin / JSFiddle) showing the effect?